# Check if paramater includes an array with special values

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to check if the parameter of my function has the values 'sender' and 'receiver'. These values should be given by an array.

This is how I check them:

```
if (is_array($target) && !in_array(array('receiver', 'sender'), $target)) {
    exit('Please check the parameters. Allowed paramaters are: sender, receiver');
}
```

I ALWAYS get the message from exit() even when my array includes both values. My array looks like that:

> array(2) {    [0]=>   string(8) "receiver"            [1]=>           string(6) "sender"
>   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking if an `sub array('receiver','sender')` exists in the `actual array` which is wrong.

You have to individually check if both the items exit in the actual array. try this:

```
if (is_array($target) && !in_array('receiver',$target) && !in_array ('sender',$target)) {
    exit('Please check the parameters. Allowed paramaters are: sender, receiver');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have an array with values in `in_array()` like you have. Try this:

```
if (is_array($target) && 
    !(in_array('receiver', $target) || in_array('sender', $target))) {
    exit('Please check the parameters. Allowed paramaters are: sender, receiver');
}
```